Doubt about inclusion in fraction ring
To prove the following:
"Let A be an integral domain and let S be a multiplicative subset of it. Prove that if I is a maximal ideal in the family of ideals of A that do not intersect S, then I is a prime ideal of A."
my book uses the fact that $S^{-1}I$ is a proper ideal and, for what's written in the text, it's also maximal in $S^{-1}A$.
However I don't know how to show that the maximality in the fraction ring comes from the maximality in the family of the text.
Namely if $S^{-1}I \subseteq S^{-1}J$ then I have $\forall i \in I, \forall s \in S, \exists j \in J, \exists t \in S$ such that $\frac{i}{s} = \frac{j}{t}$ i.e. $it=js$.
Now if this implies $I \subseteq J$ then $I = J$ and so the maximality. But how does $I \subseteq J$ comes from the relation above?

The term in English is "integral domain", not "domain of integrity."

Since $A$ is an integral domain, the localization map $A \to S^{-1}A$ is injective. We shall abuse notation slightly by saying that $A$ is literally a subset of $S^{-1}A$, so that we can intersect ideals of $S^{-1}A$ with $A$ to get ideals of $A$.
You want to show that $S^{-1}I$ is a maximal ideal of $S^{-1}A$. Simply let $J$ be any proper ideal of $S^{-1}A$ such that $$S^{-1}I \subseteq J.$$
Then, note that $I\subseteq S^{-1}I\cap A \subseteq J\cap A$.
Observations (you do this):

$J\cap A$ is an ideal of $A$ such that $(J\cap A)\cap S = \varnothing$, so that $I = J\cap A$.
$J = S^{-1}(J\cap A)$ as can be shown by working with elements.

Therefore, $J = S^{-1}I$, as desired.

Thanks, your argument is perfect. But I still don’t understand why I couldn’t go on with my approach, what was I missing?

@AlessandroTassoni In your notation, you generally have $J \subseteq S^{-1}J\cap A$ but not equality, so the inclusion $I\subseteq J$ would not follow. (A smaller ideal could have extended to $S^{-1}I$ in the localization.)

Thank you, I understand now
